# python 2.7, scraping. import re findall, changing output so that only float number is left, calculating sum

Tags: python, output, screen-scraping, html

This is from scraping

```
import re
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

I have outputs like(print numbers_in_mill.text// 
  `9.27[7]
  9.25[8]
  10.17[9]
  10.72[10]`

How do I change these outputs to // 
  `9.27
  9.25
  10.17
  10.72`

I want to remove the brackets + the number in the brackets, then I want to calculate the sum of all my `float..numbers_in_mill +=float()`

Comment: can you provide more code and explanation how you got those outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re
l = ['9.27[7]', '9.25[8]',"10.17[9]", "10.72[10]"]
for i in l:
    print(re.search("\d*\.?\d+", i).group())
```

**Output:**

```
9.27
9.25
10.17
10.72
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you both for your fast answer. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
data = ['9.27[7]', '9.25[8]',"10.17[9]", "10.72[10]"]

for d in data:
    print float(d.split("[")[0])

9.27
9.25
10.17
10.72
```